# How do I use the aggregation framework in MongoVUE?

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

Is there a way to use aggregation framework in the latest version of mongoVUE?

The only option which looks like an aggregation framework is GROUP option but I was not able to figure out how to use it.

Can someone tell me, am I looking in the right direction?
And If so, how I should write a query there.

P.S1 - it took me quite some time to be able to write MapReduce in mongoVUE

P.S2 - I am aware how to use aggregation framework from the shell.

Comment: MongoVUE hasn't been updated since last April so it doesn't support the recently released aggregation framework.

Comment: If MongoVUE allowed entering arbitrary db.runCommand() syntax then you would be able to run aggregation framework queries but I don't see that they have that capability.

Comment: If you are comfortable using the `mongo` shell, I would also suggest trying [Robomongo](http://www.robomongo.org/).  Robomongo is a cross-platform open source admin interface that allows you to open multiple shells in separate tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MongoVUE 1.6.1 ([released May 2, 2013](http://www.mongovue.com/downloads/)) now includes an Aggregate view.  If you select a collection you can choose this view from the normal menu or the right-click context menu.

Comment: This works in 1.6.5 but only returns documents in TreeView (IMHO useless) and has no 'normal' options to view in table or text views.  I can't view any document unless I click into it and can't copy any of the results.

Comment: @Mario: You should give [Robomongo](http://robomongo.org/) a try. It supports tree/table/JSON views for queries (including Aggregation Framework).

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an example of @Stennie's solution.

Given the following document in Mongo:

```
{ _id: 123456,
  Items: [
     { Name: "Item1", Color : "Red" },
     { Name: "Item2", Color : "Blue" },
     { Name: "Item3", Color : "Red" }
  ]
}
```

In MongueVue, after right clicking on the collection and selecting `Aggregate`, you can apply a pipeline such as the following, to flatten the Items, filter just the "Red" items and re-project just the item Names, from this document:

```
{ $match: {_id: 123456}},
{ $unwind: '$Items'},
{ $match: {'Items.Color': 'Red'}},
{ $project: {_id: 0, Name : '$Items.Name'}}
```

[image: Aggregate in MongoVue]